# How to retrive a single file from github using git

Tags: git, clone

I would like to learn more about this code, but I am not able to import it into my computer. How could I clone this file with git? The file is simply:

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't download it from the website?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get that file using `wget`:

1. Create a directory:

   ```
    mkdir mypycode
   ```
2. Change into that directory:

   ```
    cd mypycode
   ```
3. Identify the raw URL

- Navigate to your file on github (or your git host)
- Click on the *Raw* tab.

4. Use `wget` to download it:

   ```
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py
   ```

Comment: You are downloading the html file, you should change it to raw version ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know that.

Comment: this is github centric, OP asked about using`git`

Answer (score 6):

I suggest the following command :

```
git archive --remote=git@github.com:foo/bar.git HEAD |  tar xvf - path/to
```

Comment: You might want to make use of `tar`'s switches `--strip-components` or `--transform`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't clone a single file using git.

Git is a distributed version control system, the Idea behind its clone functionality is to have a complete copy of project and all versions of files related to that project.

Either download your file directly from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) or clone the whole project using:

```
clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository):

> If there is web interface deployed (like gitweb, cgit, Gitorious, ginatra), you can use it to download single file ('raw' or 'plain' view).
>
> If other side enabled it, you can use git archive's '--remote=' option (and possibly limit it to a directory given file resides in), for example:
>
> `$ git archive --remote=git@github.com:foo/bar.git --prefix=path/to/ HEAD:path/to/ |  tar xvf -`

Comment: ;) Just for note: `wget` is a download manager, just like `curl`, `aria2`, `axel`, `firefox` download manager, or anything else :)

Comment: What are the difference between those download manager?

Comment: Options and capabilities; With the accepted instruction, you are downloading the same file as I said with a different tool ...